# Spaceship crew looking for newly discovered planet, with a vampire on board while Earth goes dark

Tags: story-identification, books

This was by a writer who had also made books about a plague that was found by genetically engineered humans deep underwater. Later books in that series followed the women who discovered the plague through an apocalyptic USA in search of vengeance (?).

In the spaceship story, they got their energy though some kind of quantum bridge from a station in close orbit to the Sun. The vampire character had a console where every indicator was a screaming face of some kind, because that was the easiest way to gather information for him. In the end it is (implied?) that Earth has been taken over by vampires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Blindsight* (2006) by Peter Watts has a spacecraft sent from Earth outward into the solar system in order to investigate first contact. The ship has a genetically-engineered vampire (a hominid species which had gone extinct until humans resurrected them) on board. By the end of the novel, the vampires have taken over. It has a sequel called *Echopraxia* (2014), that I have not read.

The rest maybe sounds like the plot of a series of books by Watts (which I also haven't read) which starts off in a deep-sea base in the future.

Comment: thats it, thanks you so much!